# Access callee/this in Raku map code/block

Tags: raku, introspection

Is it possible to access the "callee" ("this") in Raku map code block and/or whatevercode?

E.g. if one wanted to calculate arithmetic mean

```raku
my $data = <1 10 0 7 2> ;
say $data.sum
  / $data ;   # or @$data, same as $data.elems in this numeric context
# OUTPUT: «4␤»
```

by sum of fractions

```raku
say $data.map(* / $data).sum
# OUTPUT: «4␤»
```

like

```
<1 10 0 7 2>.map({ $_ / $this }).sum   # but there's no $this
```

or

```
<1 10 0 7 2>.map( * / $this ).sum
```

If not, is there an idiomatic way to do it with only a chain of method calls on the `<…>` data literal, or different way, without storing the data in variable?

Comment: Regex hack `<…>.grep(/\d+/).map( * / $/ ).sum` or `<…>.grep(/\d+/).sum.&[/]($/)` came to my mind, but it's wrong, because of different `$/` scope.

Comment: I guess I should fix misleading "callee" term.

Answer (score 6):

There is not, to my knowledge.  You would need to be able to know how many values an iterator will produce.

Under the hood, a `foo.map: &callable` is basically a:

```
my $iterator = foo.iterator;
callable($iterator.pull-one) until iterator exhausted;
```

Note that all knowledge of the source of the iterator is lost at that point: there's just an iterator producing values.

Some types of iterators (the so-called `PredictiveIterator`s *can* tell you how many values it can still produce without actually producing them.  But most iterators are not able to do that.

I guess technically it would be possible for `map` to check whether it got a `PredictiveIterator` and set a dynamic variable with the number of values it will produce, which you could then check inside the `&callable`.

Still, it doesn't feel that this is worth the extra check for **all** `map`s and `for` loops, so I don't think a PR for such a feature would be accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand there's an issue with iterators. So you wouldn't like having this original iterator accessible via e.g. some `&?BLOCK`'s method, for the block case, as well?

Comment: It's not an issue with iterators.  It's how they are designed :).  The iterator is **not** a method on the block, the block is a parameter to a routine that takes an iterator and a block.  You can use the same block in two different maps if you give it a name (e.g. by making it a `sub`), e.g. `^10 .map: &is-prime`

Comment: I did inspect &?BLOCK keys and methods, so I know it's not, if it was, I would not issue this SO Q. Rather was wondering if it could be "bound" to it somehow, as an improvement.

Answer (score 6):

you could do this, by [`andthen`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/andthen)

```raku
<1 10 0 7 2>
andthen .sum / .elems
andthen .say
```

or

```raku
<1 10 0 7 2>
andthen .map: * / .elems
andthen .sum
andthen .say
```

Comment: `say .sum / .elems with <1 10 7 2>`

Answer (score 3):

As Liz mentioned, there's no variable that's auto-bound to the value being iterated over, but there are several ways to do what you want.  Here are three ways to do so by binding the series to the topic variable (the first is most concise and is probably what I'd write):

```
<1 10 0 7 2>.&{ .map(* / $_).sum };
given <1 10 0 7 2> { .map(* / $_).sum };
with <1 10 0 7 2> { .map(* / $_).sum };
```

Another option would be to duplicate the initial list with `xx`.  Here's one way that could look, though I'm not huge fan of it in this case.

```
(<1 10 0 7 2> xx 2).map({|$^a.map: * / $_}).sum;
```

Similarly, you could zip each element with the list as a whole (which would be overkill in this simple case, but might be useful in similar situations.)